# Pandas filtering rows with regex pattern present in the row itself

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe containing  2 columns. One containing regex pattern and the other having actual string. I want to filter out the rows where the pattern column and actual data comply with each other.

My data is in a csv file and it looks like below.

```
pattern,data
1234.*,abcd
567_.*,567_hello
```

I am expecting the output data frame to be as shown below.

```
pattern,data
567_.*,567_hello
```

I tried using lambda function on each row of DataFrame. But of no use.

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: re.compile(row[0]).match(row[1]))]
df[df.apply(lambda row: re.compile(row[0].str).match(row[1].str))]
df[df.apply(lambda row: re.compile(row['pattern']).match(row['data']))]
```

I could achieve this by constructing an all new DataFrame by iterating and filtering then. But it's not an efficient way to iterate dataframe. I am trying to work towards a more pythonic approach.

Comment: Is producing a boolean list and then using that acceptable enough? eg: `m = [bool(re.match(p, d)) for p, d in zip(df['pattern'], df['data'])]` then do `df[m]` to get the matches?

Comment: @JonClements I don't want to extend the dataframe. The dataframe is already huge with millions of records.

Comment: How is that extending a DataFrame? Also - millions of bools isn't exactly generally prohibitive...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of modification, here is the result:

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: re.compile(row['pattern']).match(row['data']) is not None, axis=1)]
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. May I know why my code didn't work? What's the reason for adding `is not None` condition?

Comment: @BarathVutukuri I believe the is not None condition is used to Return only positive matches where the pattern returns a successful match . Other Places where the pattern does not Match would be a Empty Space(Which is basically a NaN).

Comment: @BarathVutukuri apart from `is not None` , axis 1 (row) should be stated as well